# JPA 2 Criteria API with enums

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria

I have the following entity :

```
public class Role extends AbstractDomain<Long> {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idgen_x")
    @UiInfo(name = "Identifiant")
    private Long roleId;

    @Column
    @UiInfo(name = "Libellé")
    private String lib;

    @Column
    @UiInfo(name = "Provenance")
    private EnumP enumPID;
}
```

EnumP :

```
public enum EnumP {
    W, X, Y, Z;
}
```

And using JPA Criteria API I want to get a list of `Role` where `Role.enumPID` in an array contains the enum values as strings.

This is the code of the `Predicate` I tried :

```
builder.isTrue(fromRole.get(Role_.enumPID).in((Object[]) filter.getFilterSetValues()))
```

And the `filter.getFilterSetValues()` contains the enum values as strings, as following :

```
["X","Y"]
```

But I get this error message :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [X] did not match expected type [***.EnumP (n/a)]
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should adequately annotate the enum field first:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@UiInfo(name = "Provenance")
private EnumP enumPID;
```

Then you should be using the particular `EnumP` elements in your queries as params, not their String equivalents.

You would need to transform the collection of Strings into corresponding collection of `EnumP` objects:

```
public static List<EnumP> fromStringArray(String[] array){
    List<EnumP> returnList = new ArrayList<>; 

    for(String element: array){
       for(EnumP enumP: EnumP.values()){
          if(enumP.name().equals(element)){
             returnList.add(enumP);
          }
       }
    }    

    return returnList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I used the the particular `EnumP` elements ? since I'm getting them as strings (because I pass a json object to my Rest class then I pass the enum values to my dao class, so the only way I can get them is as strings)

Comment: Then you would need to consider simply making that variable as String instead of EnumP type. If you stay with enum you would have to create some sort of util method in EnumP which would return a list of EnumP elements based on the list of String as the input

Comment: Unfurtunatly I can't make `enumPID` as String, so I guess the second solution might work in this case, so you are telling me that  in the `EnumP` I have to create a method that will take the string array as param and then to return the corresponding EnumP elements, but how this can be done ?